# Mountains and their local effects on Earth's gravity

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, molecules, elements

I was once a truck driver and can feel the inertia and kinetic energy on heavy loads while traveling. While climbing mountains in the Rockies I noticed gravity was different on the side of the mountain and was easier to climb about half way up compared to the base. Is gravity changed by the mass and density of the mountain to were it may pull at an angle away from the center of Earth?
[image]

Comment: Help me better my question if needed.

Comment: Just 1% is a great deal in heavy loads and gear. I can feel the difference in pulling power compared to smaller mountains at the same angle. Rockies vs. Smokey Mountains

Comment: Can magnetic ore play a part in it?

Comment: I've traveled it regularly in winter and summer and the effect remains constant. In places on "Donner's Pass" the incline feels near flat at times. I will take everyone's word on it though and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mountains do affect gravity, but mostly because they are high and therefore farther from the centre of the Earth. Googling will find you many articles on the subject, for example [this one from New Scientist](https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn24068-gravity-map-reveals-earths-extremes/) gives a nice discussion of the subject.

However, while the changes are easily measurable using the appropriate equipment they are too small to be felt by people and far too small to affect the performance of your lorry to any noticable extent. The lowest gravitational acceleration on Earth is 9.7639 m/s$^2$ and the highest is 9.8337 m/s$^2$, which is a range of only 1%.

Answer (score 0):

While there are distortions of the gravity field, and the upper part of the "gravity lines" will probably bend in principle they way you drew them, there will be no difference that even the most sensitive rock climber could feel. I'm writing "probably" because the mountain granitic lithosphere has a lower density than the asthenosphere, which means that you will also have effects in the other way, so I think the lower portions of your lines should rather bend the opposite way.